# Average and latest value using BigQuery SQL

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery

I have some data like this:

| Product | Price | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Product A | 1.00 | 2021-11-01 |
| Product A | 2.00 | 2021-11-02 |
| Product B | 3.00 | 2021-11-01 |
| Product B | 4.00 | 2021-11-02 |

I need the avgearge price and latest price for each product in one table so it should look like this:

| Product | Avg(Price) | Latest(Price) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Product A | 1.50 | 2.00 |
| Product B | 3.50 | 4.00 |

To sum up, I just need to combine these to queries:

```
SELECT  Price  FROM MyTable
where Date = (select max(Date) FROM MyTable)
group by Product
```

and

```
SELECT  Avg(Price) FROM MyTable
group by Product
```

How can I write this to work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select distinct product, 
  avg(price) over prod as avg_price, 
  first_value(price) over(prod order by date desc) latest_price
from mytable
window prod as (partition by product)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: This worked very well. Many thanks